# how to setup realtime geolocation tracking in nodejs and android

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, geolocation, rethinkdb

Hi I want to setup realtime geolocation tracking for Android devices. This will peak to around 500 devices running app in foreground at a given time sending data to the server (average around 5-10 devices at any given time). This will be similar to what Uber does for tracking device.

I know SocketIO can be used to connect to such server but I'm not sure how to handle such data on server. I have heard node.js is good for such case but I haven't found an implementation of it anywhere. Also what kind of data store can be used in node.js to support this. Can RethinkDB be used for such implementation?

Comment: I would start by diagramming the class/service/technology map and break it down into components. There are a number of ways to go about each task that you refer to...

Comment: well so RethinkDB might be good for storing and querying the data in real time. What I'm looking for is some guidance on whether this can be scaled easily or not. I believe RethinkDB with node.js might be a good combination to build something like this on server side. I'm wondering if someone has tried this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done exactly what you are trying to do, the only difference is that for time constrains I have used phonegap for the client side, however if you are using Socket.io it should be the same concept.

As far as scalability the project is currently running on 100 devices at a time, each device updating the location as fast as every 5 seconds and as slow as 1 minute depending on if is moving or not (in normal conditions).

On the server side is running nodeJs server to process the information, the data is received as raw GPS data and I am using [googlemaps](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps) to get the approximate direction and the current prefecture (for filtering purposes).

The data is the both saved into a mysql DB using [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) and pushed to a admin pc to display the location on google maps in real time.

the only potential problem you can have scaling is the amount of data that is been stored into the DB but is nothing that clearing the table every few months wont resolve.

If this sounds like what you want to achieve let me know and I will be more than happy to provide better pointers.

Comment: Hi David can you brief example how to save the data in db?

Comment: Hi David can you provide me few directions on this